# npm/yarn certificate issue despite setting cafile

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

```
Node version: 14.21.3
npmv: 6.14.18
os: windows 10
```

```
npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
```

I DO NOT want to set `strict-ssl false`.

This wasn't always an issue -- it just started happening recently after I've been changing registry back and forward. Now, I'm seeing this issue occasionally both on default https://registry.npmjs.org and private repository. Right now issue is on private repository.

I'm on company vpn along with my other teammates who do not have any issues. I cannot upgrade the node/npm since it's a big project that will take a lot of effort to upgrade. I'm using nvm, but I've also tried without nvm.

I've tried setting cafile by following https://weekendprojects.dev/posts/fix-for-npm-error-code-self-signed-cert-in-chain/
This has worked initially, but after changing the registry a couple of times, I cannot get it to work again.

Is there a way to completely wipe off any previous nvm/npm/node/yarn installation? I'm still seeing same issue after uninstalling nvm, node and removing
/users/myUsername/.yarnrc + .npmrc
/users/myUsername/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache

Is there another place that is overriding my `npm/yarn config`?

I tried many things suggestions online, but have not been able to consistently resolve issue. I'm at the point where I'm thinking of reformatting my entire computer just to see if issue will resolve. Suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]